# Find $\log_{p}X^2$?

Tags: logarithms

Given that $\log_{p}X=5$ and $\log_{p}Y=2$, find

i) $\log_{p}X^2$

I did this, $X=p^5$ and $Y=p^2$

But how do I use them? Should I find $p$?

Comment: Please people vote the answers so that I can choose the right answer cause everybody's right!! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
Just use the identity:

$$\log_{\,b}x^n=n\log_{\,b}x .$$

Comment: Better a good hint than the whole solution. +1

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio ! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع What about this? $log_{xy}P$?

Comment: @Kiara What is $x,y$ and $P$?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع you mean the values?

Comment: @Kiara No, what informations you were given about them.

Comment: It's the same question...@حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع after that question I asked before, there was another one, $log_{p}\frac{1}{X}$ I solved that and found $-5$ and the next question is this. No other informations are included.

Comment: @Kiara So since $\log_pX=5$ and $\log_pY=2$ we have $p^{\log_pX}=X=p^5$ and similarly $p^{\log_pY}=Y=p^2.$ Therefore $XY=p^{5}\cdot p^2=p^{7}.$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع yeah thanks...I guess I got it!

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع But you know this is like $log_{p^7}P$ how is this simplified because there is a power in the base?

Comment: @Kiara Use the identity: $\log_{\,b} x=\dfrac{\log_{\,d} x}{\log_{\,d} b}.$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع okay, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Kiara You're welcome, glad I could help! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع um gonna give you a bounty :)

Comment: @Kiara I'm the one who should give you a bounty ;-)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع hahaha why is that?

Comment: @Kiara You deserve it, don't you? ;-)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع you deserve it! You help people, solving maths ain't easy! But you still help us :D :')

Answer (score 2):

$\log_p X^2 = 2 \log_p X = 2 \cdot 5 = 10$.

Answer (score 2):

$log_pX^2=log_p(p^5)^2=log_p(p^{10})=10$